# Refreshing a Flex component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder, mxml

Is there a way to refresh a component or an application back to its initial state? I have an accordion navigator that stays on the most recently selected index even if I log out. Right now, my log out function takes me back to the login page which is at state(1). If I log back in and go into the accordion, it is on the last tab I had viewed.

I would like to be able to clear any data from the controls inside the nav and reset the nav back to its default. I thought something like,

```
public function logout():void{
  currentState = "NotLoggedIn"
  myAccordion.initialize(); }
```

would work but nothing happens. This is done in Flex 4.

I know I can make a huge loop clearing each control individually and setting the selectedIndex of the accordion to 0. I was hoping for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "State".

If you have implemented states in your Flex Component, you can revert back to a previous state using:

```
component.currentState = 'myInitialState';
```

If you are not talking about states, explicitly, but rather about the internal values of the properties of the component, then Flex does not keep a history of those property values.  You can keep track of them yourself and reset them in the manually.

Once you do that, your component will be, effectively, in the initial state.

Comment: @Flextras - Yeah I should be careful about using the word "state". I do not have an initialState defined. Why is it that calling initialize doesn't work? Would it work if I first removed the accordion from the display list? Is there a global clearAll I can use?

Comment: @totbar Removing an Accordion from the DisplayList will not change any of it's properties (except possibly the parent property).  I have no idea what calling Initialize does in relation to the Accordion.  It is no a Flex LifeCycle method.  You may benefit from reading up on the Flex Component Lifecycle. ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html ).  That explains how Flex creates  and initializes it's components. A lot of the "default" state of a Component depends on the properties you set.